# Code will ask to input a digit greater than 100 and if it will be smaller than 100 so a loop will be activated else it will show "the number is > 100"

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Please tell how can I correct this code

[image: 1]

Hi, I am 12 years old and I am in 8th Class my teacher gave me this task to write a program which will ask to enter a number greater than 100 and then it will check whether it is greater than 100 or not , if not so it will apply a for loop and if it is greater than 100 so it will show that "the number is greater than 100"

Comment: @sagi look at the image he has in his question

Comment: Please paste your code here and don't use images.

Comment: You should ask for input **inside** the loop (here you infinitely tell the user they are wrong without giving them a chance to correct), also if you test as exit condition of the `while`, no need to test again with `if`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, check [ask]. Don't post images of code, errors, data, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text block.

Comment: I addition to comments above - check the condition on this line `if a <=10:`

Comment: Obviously you need to get a new input somewhere ... you don't. Why? Use pythontutor.com or a debugger to step through your code to see the code flow. You also may need to fix <=100 to be consistent with your input-texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code should look like:

```
a = int(input("Enter a value bigger than 100: "))

# loop ends if the number is bigger than 100 otherwise it will run forever
while a <= 100: 

    print("try again")
    # asks the use for input 
    a = int(input("Enter a value bigger than 100: "))

print("Congrats, you entered a value bigger than 100")
```